# Configuring Homestead to work with MySQL Workbench

Tags: laravel, mysql-workbench, homestead

I just started using Homestead today and so far I don't think I know what I am doing, previously I was using the inbuilt PHP server that comes with Laravel and I had MySQL server and workbench installed separately on my computer.

With this setup I was able to connect to my database with ease, however since I got my Homestead running I can't seem to access that database again. This error keeps popping up:

```
3/3 ErrorException in Connector.php line 47: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] 
Access denied for user 'myproject_db101'@'localhost' (using password: YES) 
(View: /home/vagrant/Projects/myproject/resources/views/layout/index.blade.php) 
(View: /home/vagrant/Projects/myproject/resources/views/layout/index.blade.php)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show the credentials you're using in Workbench, and any customizations you made to the Homestead Vagrantfile?

Comment: Like i said i am new to all this so i couldn't even make any customizations even if i wanted to lol

Comment: As for the credentials apart from the stuff i entered in my Laravel project i haven't entered anything anywhere else again, or am i supposed to configure something in homestead for my database to work?

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused. Please try to clarify your question by showing your connection parameters (minus password), explaining where & when you get the above error, etc.

Comment: This is a new installation of homestead, where can i find the connection parameters?

Answer (score 26):

I was facing the same issue and I tried below steps to fix it. Please let me know if they work for you.

1. Note the homestead ip address for your vagrant box. It is available in Homestead.yaml file under ~/.homestead directory. This directory location would be different on different OS. But since you have already installed vagrant with homestead you should know its location. For me the ip address was 192.168.10.10.
2. Open up the Mysql Connection wizard and provide the below settings

   `hostname  = 192.168.10.10
   port = 3306
   username = homestead
   password = secret`
3. Test Your connection

For me these settings worked. Check if they work for you.

Comment: Yeah, as I said - local ip to connect might be different and depends on the way your homestead is configured. You would need to identify the ip from your settings and use that to connect.

Comment: I was able to connect with these settings as well. Thank you! @OmarTariq I believe the `0` at the end of the IP address gets dropped off, so `192.168.10.1 == 192.168.10.10`

Comment: I was trying with these credentials but no avail, then I copied and pasted what you put in there and it worked. I probably had a typo or something. :)

Answer (score 2):

These other answers might have worked for you guys, but in case anyone has a case like mine, I'm just going to provide what worked for me. Hopefully it helps someone out. I'm working on a brand new homestead installation as of today, but on a very old mac in case thats relevant.

What worked for me was using the regular localhost ip of my machine as the host, and then the homested/secret combination for the password, and using the default port but with a 0 at the end.
This adds up to be the following settings:

**Connection method: Standard (TCP/IP)**

Host: `127.0.0.1`
Username: `homestead`
Password: `secret`
Port: `33060`

Hopefully this helps someone out. Its the only configuration that worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me on a fresh Homestead install. Saved me right when I was about to toss my Linux dev laptop experiment and go back to Windows!

Answer (score 1):

Try using homestead's default MySQL credentials: User: `root` Password: `secret`

If you are accessing the database from your computer via MySQL Workbench (not from within the homestead VM), you can use `localhost:33060` (note: non-standard port). This is mapped to port 3306 within your VM.

From your application and any time you're working from within the homestead VM, you can connect to the database normally as localhost on port 3306.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but when i try this i get "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused "

Answer (score 0):

Very likely a configuration issue. Either the user `'myproject_db101'@'localhost'` has no password set or is not allowed to connect from localhost. You need another user with proper rights (e.g. the root user) to fix permissions for that user.